# how to get all data from a request

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I receive data from the server and try to get "name" from the "one" object and get an undefined error. If you remove the replacement in request, the line "fetchData (response.data)" with "fetchData (response.data.one)" and in the selector "return state.one.name;" to "return state.name;" the result returns data. What is causing this error? Query and reference to the same objects.

request

```
export function fetchData (data) {
    return {
        type: "GET_DATA_REQUEST",
        payload: data
    }
}

export function fetchDataRequest(url) {
    return(dispatch)=> {
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => {
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        throw new Error(response.statusText);
                    }
                    return response;
                }
            )
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => dispatch(fetchData(response.data)))
    }
}
```

selector

```
export const getRequestCity = (state) => {
    return state.one.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the object `one` is present before accessing it like below -

```
export const getRequestCity = (state) => {
    if (state.one) {
        return state.one.name;      
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks helped. Can you tell me why the error occurs in the first option?

Comment: Maybe `getRequestCity ` method was getting called before the `state` is updated. To avoid the exception, we can first check for the object before accessing its key-values.